# Comparing constexpr function parameter in constexpr-if condition causes error

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++17, static-assert, if-constexpr

I'm trying to compare a function parameter inside a constexpr-if statement.

Here is a simple example:

```
constexpr bool test_int(const int i) {
  if constexpr(i == 5) { return true; }
 else { return false; }
}
```

However, when I compile this with GCC 7 with the following flags:
`g++-7 -std=c++1z test.cpp -o test`
I get the following error message:

```
test.cpp: In function 'constexpr bool test_int(int)':
test.cpp:3:21: error: 'i' is not a constant expression
 if constexpr(i == 5) { return true; }
```

However, if I replace `test_int` with a different function:

```
constexpr bool test_int_no_if(const int i) { return (i == 5); }
```

Then the following code compiles with no errors:

```
int main() {
  constexpr int i = 5;
  static_assert(test_int_no_if(i));
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the constexpr-if version fails to compile, especially since the static_assert works just fine.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why constexpr(i == 5) and not just i==5?

Comment: any why so complicated? why not return i==5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

> In a constexpr if statement, the value of condition must be a
>   contextually converted **constant expression** of type bool.

Then, from [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression):

> Defines an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

Obviously, `i == 5` is not a constant expression, because `i` is a function parameter which is evaluated at run time. That is why the compiler complains.

When you use a function:

```
constexpr bool test_int_no_if(const int i) { return (i == 5); }
```

then it might be evaluated during the compile time depending on whether it's parameter is known at compile time or not.

If `i` is defined like:

```
constexpr int i = 5;
```

then the value of `i` is known during the compile time and `test_int_no_if` might be evaluated during the compile too making it possible to call it inside `static_assert`.

Also note, that marking function parameter as `const` does not make it a compile time constant. It just means that you cannot change the parameter inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

A constexpr function can be called with non-constexpr arguments, in which case it behaves like a normal function, so the code must still compile as if it were not constexpr.

In short, there's nothing in test_int_no_if that depends on i being constexpr, while in test_int(), there is.  ("constexpr if" only works with compile time expressions.)

Comment: This is the most useful answer IMHO